# COPY csv-file in the database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv

I am not familiar with the work of CSV files, so I decided to ask for advice. I work in PostgreSQL

```
COPY mark(id_p,mark,id_dis,date) 
FROM 'D:\bd2.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

I have such simple code in which I read the data from a file and then immediately enter it into the table, but when the user enters the data and loads it, he has no idea which ID is in the table (I have in the table two ID) and enters the necessary information. And now I have a BIG QUESTION.

How can I read data from a file, but before that I, so to speak, “process” them to additionally indicate the ID needed to enter the table. I have no idea how to function - do it ......

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION csv_test( csv_name_f TEXT)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
BEGIN

COPY mark(id_p,mark,id_dis,date) 
FROM 'D:\bd2.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

END;
$BODY$;
```

If you have an option how to solve it. You can throw a small example, I will be very grateful.

P.S. I was suggested use a "temporary table" since I haven't worked with it, I can't figure out how to do it ..

Comment: Do you want to auto-generate an artificial primary key? Please describe which column you are talking about. The table definition would be helpful.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Inside my table of “marks” I have 4 fields (I do not consider the identifier of the table itself) of which two fields are foreign keys of other tables (identifiers).
I need to upload a CSV file with data that should then be included in the “MARK” table.
But since the table contains fields with identifiers, I first need to “process” this data from the file, and then add it to the “MARK” table.
I was offered to use a temporary table, but I do not know how to use it

Comment: Create a temporary table that exactly matches the incoming data and load the data into it. Then populate the target table with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I understand how it should be in my head. So I ask for a small example so that I can better understand

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Because I did not work with temporary tables